# Populate data string in Ajax with For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I have a loop inserting select tag based on how many ROWs. My select tag will have id selID0, selID1, selID2... I wish to call and ajax function to check which tag is not selected when clicking the submit button.

I have tried to build the data string in the Ajax function using a for loop. I am not sure how to build the string or is there another to insert the string? Please help, thanks.

```
do while i < Cint(sROW)

    response.write "<tr>"
    response.write "<td>"
    response.write "    <select class='form-control' id='selID" & i & "' name='selID" & i & "'>"
    response.write "        <option value=''>Select</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='a'>a</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='b'>b</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='c'>c</option>"
    response.write "        <option value='d'>d</option>"
    response.write "    </select>"
    response.write "</td>"
    response.write "</tr>"
    i=i+1
loop
```

The Ajax function

```
function checkselect() {

var url_to  = 'ax_postcheckselect.asp';
For (i = 0, i< <%=sROW %>, i++)
{
    var str = """selID""" + i + ":$(""#selID" + i + """).val(),"
    var kae = kae + str
};

     $.ajax({
         url        : url_to,
         type   : 'POST',
         data    :  { "txtRow":$("#txtRow").val(),
             kae
          },
```

Basically I wish to populate the data part to be

```
       data    :  { "txtRow":$("#txtRow").val(),
             "selID0":$("#selID0").val(),
             "selID1":$("#selID1").val(),
             "selID2":$("#selID2").val(),
             "selID3":$("#selID3").val(),

               and so on depending on how many sROWs.    
          },
```

Please help.

Comment: why not use $('form').serialze() and send over ALL of the form data?

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your reply, can you show me a rough idea how to use $('form').serialze(), your help is upmost appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, no problem :)

[$('form').serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) will take all of the elements in a form and essentially serialize them, which means you don't have to specify your form data individually (ie: data: { frmElement: val, frmElement2: val2, etc...)

```
function checkselect() {

var url_to  = 'ax_postcheckselect.asp';
For (i = 0, i< <%=sROW %>, i++)
{
    var str = """selID""" + i + ":$(""#selID" + i + """).val(),"
    var kae = kae + str
};

 $.ajax({
     url        : url_to,
     type   : 'POST',
     data    :  $('form').serialize(),
         kae
      },
```